# How to transfer USDT with .call

Tags: solidity, usdt, address.call

I need to transfer USDT Token (Not ETH) using .call with solidity. ¿Some idea?
Thanks.

Comment: USDT is transferred by calling the transfer function on the USDT contract. To avoid accidentally black-holing it, better to call the approve function and then the receiving contract calls transferFrom.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't know how I could do it using the low level function .call or .delegatecall?

Comment: then you are basically asking how to call *any* function with call - it's not like those functions are special

Answer (score 0):

I dont know why do you want to use `.call()` but `.send()`.anyway here is the code for your reference:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol";

contract MyContract {
    // The contract address of the USDT token
    address usdtContractAddress = "0xdAC17F958D2ee523a2206206994597C13D831ec7";
    
    function transferUSDT(address _to, uint256 _value) public {
        // Call the transfer function on the USDT contract
        IERC20(usdtContractAddress).transfer(_to, _value).call();
    }
}
```

Comment: The code as it is doesn't compile.